# Javascript Input Length Validation onsubmit, Submit anyway

Tags: javascript, validation, input, onsubmit

I try to validate the user input and check the length of the value if its smaller than x then it should `alert("..")`. I catch this code together with some code I found here and there, and I tried many things out, but nothing worked. It always does the submit.
If I write

```
<form ... onsubmit="false">..</form>
```

it submits anyway, but it shouldn't or not?

Here is my code snippet, I hope anyone can help me.

```
<form name="form" action="go.php" id="form" onsubmit="return validate('text',5)">
    Text: <input type="text" name="text" id="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<script>
    function validate(input,length) {
        submit = true;
        var elemlength = document.getElementbyId(input).value.length;
        alert(":" + elemlength);
        if(elemlength < length){
            submit=false;
            alert("ivalid length");
        }
        return submit;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: are you using any library? Jquery, angular .. ? I think if you only use native javascript .. it could be some hard work.

Comment: no i'am not using any library, should i better? i just want it simple, because i don't know much about js.

Comment: If you don't understand JavaScript, attempting to learn a library won't help much. [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) and  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript) may help you learn.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have a typo it is `document.getElementById` not `document.getElementbyId`.

```html
<form name="form" id="form" onsubmit="return validate('text',5)">
    Text: <input type="text" name="text" id="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<script>
    function validate(input,length) {
        submit = true;
        var elemlength = document.getElementById(input).value.length;
        alert(":" + elemlength);
        if(elemlength < length){
            submit=false;
            alert("ivalid length");
        }
        
        return submit;
    }
</script>
```

If you want to prevent form submission your code should go like this `<form ... onsubmit="return false">..</form>`

Answer (score -1):

```js
"use strict";

let button = document.querySelector('#button');
let input = document.querySelector('#text');
let minLength = 5;

button.addEventListener('click', validate);

function validate(event) {
    if (input.value.length < minLength) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('Input text is smaller then ' + minLength);
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="form" action="go.php" id="form">
    Text: <input type="text" name="text" id="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id ="button"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, for the work you have done! But 90% of your code i don't understand. In my Code there was just a Letter in small, than it should be big.